# Question about a simultaneous "massive" downvote

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

17 simultaneous downvote (only on Question posted, I think):
[image]

May I ask if there is some "systematic" reason ?

Thanks

Comment: If it helps, some pointers to basic information about serial voting are in the [corresponding tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/serial-voting/info).

Comment: with the new system that can be wiped out with 4 upvotes. or 3 accepted answers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  In my experience the system will undo such an obvious serial downvoting spree within the next day.  If it *doesn't* catch this, the moderators can be alerted by flagging one of these downvoted questions "for moderator attention."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are serial downvotes classified as anomalous? What to do about a sequence of downvotes?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/when-are-serial-downvotes-classified-as-anomalous-what-to-do-about-a-sequence-o)

Comment: @ArcticChar - fine Thanks :-) We can close/delete my question.

Comment: Here's a better question what counts as massive when you can recover from 100 downvotes with 14 accepts, or 20 upvotes ?

Comment: General advice: wait 24 hours and see if these downvotes are automatically canceled.