# Why has my post been downvoted for no reason, and can moderators investigate posts that have been downvoted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, up-votes

In one of my posts under *Timeline*, there are 4 upvotes and 2 downvotes, and the score of the post is 2. My reputation increased +36 by these actions. What happened? How many users have voted for my post?

I am asking this because my post is not a low-quality post and I think that it doesn't deserve any downvotes.

In general, can moderators interfere with posts that have been down-voted without any reason?

Comment: Upvotes are worth 10 rep points each; downvotes deduct two points each.  So $4\times 10 - 2\times 2 = 36$, is the net gain in rep.  As for the net score of 2, you had 4 upvotes - 2 downvotes = 2.

Comment: Since no user can vote both *up* and *down* at the same time on the same post, if you received 4 upvotes and 2 downvotes, then you've received a total of 6 votes from 6 distinct user accounts.

Comment: You don't know, C.F.G., that the downvoters had no reason. All you know is they chose not to state any reason. These sites don't require downvoters to state any reason. Some consider this a bug, some, a feature, but in any event if you want to see the pros & cons you can look at earlier discussions here with the down-votes tag. And moderators can't do a thing about it, nor should they.

Comment: although this isn't what happened to you, actually *reverting* a downvote and upvoting would cause a 12 point rep swing

Comment: @CalvinKhor maybe this should be written as an answer for anyone in the future having the same question?

Comment: Sorry, I was busy and now the question is closed @user400188

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the help centre (which can be found by clicking the ? icon on the top black bar, to the right), upvotes give you +10 reputation, and downvotes cost -2 reputation. Indeed, 4 upvotes and 2 downvotes gives you $4 \times 10 - 2 \times 2  =36$ reputation in total, and since each user can only cast one upvote or downvote per question, $6$ users voted on your post in total.

Regarding your second question, it's not the moderators' job to investigate every single downvote. The script checks once every 24 hours for anomalous voting patterns, and if you have gotten a few suspicious votes, they will be reversed automatically (see [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3068) for more information).

For all the downvotes that were made in good faith, you will have to accept that you may never know the true reason, as Stack Exchange sites do not require downvoters to state a reason at all. This discussion is certainly not new on this site (see this [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) post), but if every downvoter was forced to leave a comment, there would always be the danger that the asker/answerer would retaliate. This behaviour is not conducive for the site and I believe that we should try to provide a safe and healthy environment for asking and answering questions on this site, as much as possible. You might want to leave a comment under your post to request that the downvoters explain, but this does not guarantee a response from them.