# Why I recently lost lot of reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, serial-voting

[image]

Recently, I got lots of negative reputation. Why? I guess, I earned all those reputation by accepting answer. But, some answers were written by me. Although, I lost reputation. But, I didn't get reputation for accepting that as answer.

Comment: It may be possible that someone is deliberately downvoting you since it is not possible to get so many downvotes in a matter of minutes, perhaps system will reverse these downvotes tomorrow.

Comment: See: [When are serial downvotes classified as anomalous? What to do about a sequence of downvotes?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3068) (There is also an older post - which might be cute if you are fan of puns, but the title makes it more difficult to find: [Cereal downvotes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9179).)

Comment: Accept an answer if it helped you or was useful, not to earn +2 points.

Comment: According to the [reputation section of your profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/876873/istiak?tab=reputation), these are all downvotes. The links provided by Martin Sleziak should cover what to do.

Comment: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vorWH.png) of the above. It correlates with your recent two negatively voted questions. To help avoid this in the first place, you could try be a little more cordial than "Don't suggest to solve the problem any other way", "Can't you see what I asked?", "Sorry! What the hell is it $\Re$?" (although, this isn't a guarantee anyway)

Comment: The downvotes have now been [automatically removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76CWe.png).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need not to worry about this. Someone who has deliberately downvoted most of your posts but you need not worry. This is serial voting and your reputation will be restored to you by 5 am UTC. If the 24 hours have already passed and the suspicious votes have not been reversed, you can then flag one of your own posts for "in need of moderator intervention" and explain in detail what happened. Also you can go to the bottom and click on contact (or in case you can't find it here [is the link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/contact). Just explain them if within 24 hours your rep hasn't been restored and you feel someone is deliberately doing it. You will then soon receive information in your gmail from them within 24 hours.

[To get more details about serial voting, what I need to do etc click on this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829)

Comment: I don't care of reputation. The problem is actually "moderator should do something against this type of things".

Comment: @Istiak It is most often the case that moderator action is best initiated by *flagging*. That is the way it is meant to go.

Comment: @Istiak don't worry [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) handles all the things and for mod attention you should flag one flag for mod attention as mod have 100s of work. Btw I am not able aware of which work :)